# парсер на PHP c <Yandex:full-text> и <[!CDATA[много текста]]>

Tags: php, парсер, xml

С помощью `simplexml_load_file($url, "SimpleXMLElement", LIBXML_NOCDATA)` добился следующего:
Имею теперь почти читаемый массив:

```
[19] => SimpleXMLElement Object
                    (
                        [title] => В Канске вернувшийся из мест заключения отец устроил своим детям урок "воспитания"
                        [pubDate] => Wed, 01 Mar 2023 14:22:36 +0700
                        [category] => Канск

                        [yandex:full-text] => В Канске у неоднократно судимого местного жителя изъяты дети....<br>
                    )
```

Данная !CDATA раскрылась. Но я так и не смог вытащить данные из `[yandex:full-text]`. !Старый код работающий без CDATA c яндекс-тегом yandex:full-text, тоже не смог `$full_text=$item->children('yandex',true);`
Как быть? И что делать?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Реализовал так:

```
foreach ( $xml->channel->item as $key => $item)  
    { 
            $full_text_preview=mb_substr((string)$item->{'yandex:full-text'}, 0, $count_simbols, 'utf-8');
            $full_text=(string)$item->{'yandex:full-text'};
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Скорее всего вам и не нужен флаг `LIBXML_NOCDATA`. Достать строку из тега `<yandex:full-text />` можно приведением объекта к строке, даже, если содержимое тега заключено в `<![CDATA[...]]>`.

Если у вас валидный XML с определенными неймспейсами, как в [этом примере](https://dzen.ru/help/news/export-content/export.html#example), то это можно сделать так:

```php
$rss = simplexml_load_file(__DIR__ . '/rss.xml');

foreach ($rss->channel->item as $item) {
    $fullText = (string) $item->children('yandex', true)->{'full-text'};
    // или
    $fullText = (string) $item->children('http://news.yandex.ru')->{'full-text'};
    print "{$fullText}\n";
}
```

Единственная польза от `LIBXML_NOCDATA` в том, что при вызове `var_dump` или `print_r`, вы будете видеть содержимое узлов с CDATA.

Comment: У меня он не сработал почему-то. Разбираться почему не работает не стал, так как уже имею рабочий код. (см.ниже)